# Why does Pandas give me only one SettingWithCopyWarning?

Tags: python, pandas, warnings

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'UID':[1,2,3],
                     'Price':[10,20,30],
                     'Shipped':[2,4,6]})
grouped = mydf.groupby('UID').aggregate(np.sum)
# Call 1
mydf['Price'].loc[:] = np.round(grouped['Price'], 2)
# Call 2
mydf['Shipped'].loc[:] = grouped['Shipped']
```

The line that I have preceded with `Call 1` executes with no errors or warnings. The line that I have preceded with `Call 2` results in a `SettingWithCopyWarning` error. Why does the one result in the error and not the other? What can I do in my second call in order to get rid of this error?

My code executes fine, I'm just tired on seeing this one lone error every time I run my tests.

Comment: what's your pandas version? I get no warning for either on 0.17.1

Comment: pd.__version__ returns '0.17.0', and I am running python version 3.4.3 on windows 7.

Comment: OK I can reproduce, if you remove the loc calls there is no warning: `mydf['Price'] = np.round(grouped['Price'], 2)
# Call 2
mydf['Shipped'] = grouped['Shipped']` also the order of the calls doesn't matter, you get the same warning

Answer (score 1):

No SettingWithCopyWarning error

```
mydf['Shipped'].values[:] = grouped['Shipped']
```

Comment: Indeed, but `...values[:]` works great. If you update you're answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Nvm, this actually doesn't work. It ends up messing up my np.sum() on some of the columns in question. Possibly due to NaN's?